# Issues mapping an enum with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, enums, mapping, persistence

I've got a problem mapping this enum:

```
public enum KOBEnum {
Kost,
Baat
}
```

It is mapped in the class 'KostOfBaat' like this:

```
@Column(name ="KostOfBaatEnum")
private KOBEnum kobEnum;
```

It has a getter and setter. The corresponding column in the database is 'KostOfBaatEnum' so it isn't a spelling error, and the data is put in the database as an ordinal.

I've tried pretty much everything but I still get an error mapping this class. This is my output after running a sample JPQL query:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [KostOfBaatEnum] is not defined in the domain class [persistence.KostOfBaat], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: KostOfBaatEnum
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[KostOfBaatEnum-->kostofbaat.KostOfBaatEnum]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(persistence.KostOfBaat --> [DatabaseTable(kostofbaat)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(persistence.Analyse --> [DatabaseTable(analyse)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(persistence.KostOfBaat --> [DatabaseTable(kostofbaat)]).
```

Comment: show all your mapping please.

Comment: It is complaining about a field "KostOfBaatEnum" and you have a field "kobEnum" (allegedly). So you find where you have put a field KostOfBaatEnum